# Iterator and Pointer on Matrix in C

Tags: c, pointers, matrix, iterator

For a JPEG image compression, I manipulate image in grey levels and 8bits by pixels

I have this type of matrix I dynamically allocated :

```
typedef char pixel_t;
pixel_t ** pix_matrix;
```

after allocating and filling it, I have a bidimensional array with the values (from -128 to +127) of the luminance of the picture.

For the JPEG compression, I need to iterate this array in zigzag like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJULt.jpg]

So I want to create an Iterator structure for this type. This iterator must have 'current' and 'begin' members and I want those members to be pointers to the current element and first one of the matrix.  In other words, I want to store the addresses and not the indexes. But after hours of tests, prints and researches, I couldn't find the way to make that possible. What type of pointer do I have to use? how make it point to the first address of my matrix? Is my request simply possible?

And if all of this is possible, how can I get the next element, and the value of the current one?

Comment: I just edited y post. The char type is used because my pixels are is encoded on 8 bits and they are signed.

Comment: You have tagged this question with C, but iterators that follow the pattern `for (Zigzagger z = img.begin(); z != img.end(); z++) proc(*z);` are typically used in C++. Have you mixed up the tags?

Comment: Note that a plain `char` may be a signed or unsigned quantity; different platforms _do_ implement it differently.  Your `pixel_t` type should, therefore, be `typedef signed char pixel_t;` for maximum reliability.

Comment: Is there anything to distinguish this from [Transform matrix 2D to 1D](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18801547/)?  The zigzag scanning pattern certainly looks the same as in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an interator structure:

```
struct zigzag_t {
    int width;      // width, must be initialised
    int height;     // height, must be initialised
    int x;          // current x index
    int y;          // current y index
    int underway;   // dummy value to start at (0, 0)
};
```

which you must initialise with the width and height of your image. Write an interator function, so that you can use this iterator like this:

```
struct zigzag_t zz = {8, 8};

while (zigzag_next(&zz)) {
    printf("(%d, %d)\n", zz.y, zz.x);
}
```

The iterator itself is not too complicated: If the sum of the `x` and `y` indices is odd, you walk southwest until you hit either the west or south edge. If the sum is even, you walk northeast until you hit either the north or east wall. If you hit the ne or sw edges, the east and south edges get priority. The iteration ends after you have visited the se edge.

Because the struct starts off with `x` and `y` both zero, the first point is (0, 1). In order to fix this, the dummy field `underway`, which also is zero, is used.

The iterator must be reset if you want to use it a second time. better yet, define and initialise a fresh iterator.

The iterator function:

```
int zigzag_next(struct zigzag_t *zz)
{
    int odd = (zz->x + zz->y) % 2;

    if (zz->underway == 0) {
        zz->x = zz->y = 0;
        zz->underway = 1;
        return 1;
    }

    if (odd) {
        /* walk southwest */

        int w_edge = zz->x == 0;
        int s_edge = zz->y == zz->height - 1;

        if (s_edge) {
            zz->x++;
            return zz->x < zz->width;
        } else if (w_edge) {
            zz->y++;
        } else {
            zz->x--;
            zz->y++;
        }
    } else {
        /* walk northeast */

        int e_edge = zz->x == zz->width - 1;
        int n_edge = zz->y == 0;

        if (e_edge) {
            zz->y++;
            return zz->y < zz->height;
        } else if (n_edge) {
            zz->x++;
        } else {
            zz->x++;
            zz->y--;
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

This solution returns the x and y positions, which you can use as indices to your double pointer to pixel data. It would not be hard to extend the struct to hold the base pointer to your pixel data and have the iterator function return a pointer to a pixel or `NULL` if the iteration has run out.

An example solution with pointers is below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef char pixel_t;

struct zigzag_t {
    pixel_t **p;    // base data
    int width;      // width, must be initialised
    int height;     // height, must be initialised
    int x;          // current x index
    int y;          // current y index
    int underway;   // dummy value to start at (0, 0)
};

pixel_t *zigzag_next(struct zigzag_t *zz)
{
    int odd = (zz->x + zz->y) % 2;

    if (zz->underway == 0) {
        zz->x = zz->y = 0;
        zz->underway = 1;
        return *zz->p;
    }

    if (odd) {
        /* walk southwest */

        int w_edge = zz->x == 0;
        int s_edge = zz->y == zz->height - 1;

        if (s_edge) {
            zz->x++;
            if (zz->x == zz->width) return NULL;
        } else if (w_edge) {
            zz->y++;
        } else {
            zz->x--;
            zz->y++;
        }
    } else {
        /* walk northeast */

        int e_edge = zz->x == zz->width - 1;
        int n_edge = zz->y == 0;

        if (e_edge) {
            zz->y++;
            if (zz->y == zz->height) return NULL;
        } else if (n_edge) {
            zz->x++;
        } else {
            zz->x++;
            zz->y--;
        }
    }

    return zz->p[zz->y] + zz->x;
}

int main()
{
    pixel_t *data[] = {
        "abcde", "fghij", "klmno", "pqrst", "uvwxy"
    };

    struct zigzag_t zz = {data, 5, 5};

    for (;;) {
        pixel_t *p = zigzag_next(&zz);

        if (p == NULL) break;
        putchar(*p);
    }
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

This solution is a C solution. There is no `begin` member function; initialisation is done via simple struct initialisation. There is no increment operator and no `end` member function; moving the iterator forward and checking for the end is done in a plain old function.

You have tagged the question C, but iterators are more frequent in C++, where they can be implemented as classes. The above C example may serve as a base for such an implementation.

Comment: Firstly, thanks a lot for your answer, I will try this and get back to you.

This is a C program, no doubt about it, but i need this kind of structure, similar to C++ of Java, to make the iteration of the structure cleaner and better.

Answer (score 0):

Something nice and simple.

- Function `next` is the iterator; it returns true until all cells have been visited.
- A variable of type `POSITION` holds the iterator state.
- Function `current` returns a pointer to the current cell in the matrix.

Demo function `sample_application` puts it all together.

```
#define MAX_XY 7

typedef struct { int x, y; } POSITION;

static int sign_of(int i)
{
    return i < 0 ? -1 : i > 0 ? 1 : 0;
}

static int get_direction(int a, int b, int odd_is_forward)
{
    return sign_of(((a + b) % 2 == odd_is_forward || b >= MAX_XY ? MAX_XY : 0) - a);
}

int next(POSITION *pos)
{
    int x = pos->x;
    int y = pos->y;
    pos->x += get_direction(x, y, 0);
    pos->y += get_direction(y, x, 1);
    return x < MAX_XY || y < MAX_XY;
}

pixel_t *current(POSITION *pos)
{
    return &pix_matrix[pos->y][pos->x];
}

void sample_application()      // just demonstrating the use of POSITION
{
    POSITION pos = {-1, -1};   // always start from these dummy coordinates
    while (next(&pos))         // this iterates through the matrix
    {
        int coord_x = pos.x;   // this is how you get the current coordinates
        int coord_y = pos.y;
        *current(&pos) = 12;   // this is how you access the current cell
    }
}
```